# How can I add mean labels to a bar chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add the mean of each condition at the base of my bar chart in R. The final product looks something like this in excel (note the means are displayed at the base of each bar):
[image]

My current code is as follows:

```
pmrtBar <- ggplot(reslagdfClean,aes(x=Condition, y=PMMissProp*100)) + stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar", fill = cbPalette) +
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=12)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = "errorbar", width=.1, size = .25) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,50)) + 
  labs(x = "Condition", y="Mean Mean Miss Proportion (%)") +
  apatheme
pmrtBar
```

I am new the R environment. Any feedback on the code above is also appreciated.

Comment: could you attach a part of the data you use for the plot

Comment: You can use `geom_text` for that. For example, adding `geom_text(aes(y = 31, label = PMMissProp*100))` might give you what you want.

Comment: [See here for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22780779/2204410)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always good to add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610) to your question.

Converting my comment to an answer with the use of some example data:

```
# example data
dat <- data.frame(id = c("ACT","Blank","None"),
                  mn = c(0.3833,0.38,0.4033),
                  se = c(0.1,0.15,0.12))

# creating the plot
ggplot(dat, aes(x=id, y=mn, fill=id)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.7) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = mn + se, ymin = mn - se), width=0.25) +
  geom_text(aes(y = 0.2, label = paste(mn*100, "%"))) +
  labs(x = "\nCondition", y = "Proportion (%)\n") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0.15, 0.55, 0.05), labels = scales::percent) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0.15,0.55)) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 14) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_line(linetype = 2, color = "grey80", size = 1))
```

which results in:

[image]