# Add customized labels over bars in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, label

I am plotting a simple barplot in ggplot2 and I need to show, over each bar of the plot, something (a number, or a string..) which is not related to this dataset I'm using.
For example with the following instructions:

```
ggplot(diamonds,aes(cut))+geom_bar()
```

I get this graph:

[image]

And I want to show, over the bars, the elements of the array:

```
val<-c(10,20,30,40,50)
```

Obtaining a result like this other graph

[image]

I tried using **geom_text** in this way:

```
ggplot(diamonds,aes(cut))+geom_bar()+
geom_text(aes(label=val))
```

But I get the following error message

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (53940): label, x
```

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777245/how-to-add-custom-labels-from-a-dataset-on-top-of-bars-using-ggplot-geom-bar-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are making a histogram with `geom_bar` and there is no `y` variable specified. In order to apply [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22780779/2204410), you need to summarise the `cut` variable first:

```
val<-c(10,20,30,40,50)

library(dplyr)
diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut) %>%
  tally() %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = cut, y = n)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = val), vjust = -0.5, position = position_dodge(0.9))
```

which gives you:

[image]